# In C# , in Visual Studio, using a Console Application, is there a way to make methods in a class and call them in main program using readline?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In C# , in Visual Studio, using a Console Application, is there a way to make methods in a class and call them in main program using readline?

Aka, a way to choose which methods to open when the program is running.

Comment: There is a lot of these options. Are you targeting full .net framework or .net core?

Comment: ehm. not sure. its a console app. and sofar its just for small school assigment methods.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is a switch statement for <4 cases, and a Dictionary for 4 or more cases.

```
class Program
{
    private static IDictionary<string, Action> MethodMappings = new Dictionary<string, Action> {
       {"Method1", Method1},
       {"Method2", Method2},
       ...
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {

       var methodCall = Console.ReadLine();

       if (!MethodMappings.ContainsKey(methodCall)) {
          //unrecognized command
       }

       MethodMappings[methodCall].Invoke();
    }

    private static void Method1() { ... }
    private static void Method2() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very much possible using Reflection. Here is sample code to help you out:

```
class Program
{

    public static void Hello1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nHello 1");
    }

    public static void Hello2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nHello 2");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            String method = Console.ReadLine();

            Type methodType = typeof(Program);
            MethodInfo voidMethodInfo = methodType.GetMethod(method);
            voidMethodInfo.Invoke(method,null);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information you can visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).

Comment: As much as this is possible, I do not recommend this practice, as it enforces unnatural coding habits. It's better to just use a `switch()` tree or some `if`s, as it also gives more control.